# Is "Style" a reserved word in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reserved-words

My IDE (Sublime Text 2) just highlighted `Style` in the same manner it highlights `Object` or `Math` in javascript mode. Is `Style` used for something in javascript? This only happened for uppercase `Style`, not `style`.

[image]

A quick test in gist did not result in the same highlighting: https://gist.github.com/3230637

Edit: Added `Foo` to show it's not just constructor syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't a reserved word, but it is an object in the DOM.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp

Many IDE's will highlight this because it is a common object, like `Object` and `Math`.

Comment: Thanks for the further explanation (that it's common, but not reserved).

Comment: @zzzzBov There appear to be 2 camps. I'm in the camp that does *not* involve a smear website.

Comment: @KendallFrey, It's not so much to say that the information in inherently invalid. It's just to provide a warning that the content is a secondary source of information at best. I'd much prefer to see people linking to specifications or wiki-based references, as they provide a canonical definition, or one that could be improved as-needed respectively.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why your IDE is highlighting `Style` like that, but to answer your question, no, style is not a reserved word.

[List of reserved words in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words)

Comment: Thanks Adam and @RobW for your initial answer.

Answer (score 1):

Nope: [Reserved Words In JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words)